# i cant figure the return fuction for the following code to work like this

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
def hello_worddict(doc):
    string_alpha = ""
    list_of_noalpha = []
    worddict = {}
    newlist = []

    for char in doc:
        if char.isalpha():
            string_alpha += char
        elif char == "'" or char == "-":
            if (string_alpha[-1]).isalpha():
                string_alpha += char
            else:
                string_alpha += " "
                list_of_noalpha.append(char)
        alpha_list = string_alpha.split()

        def remover(char):
            for word in alpha_list:
                if word[-1] == char:
                    del(alpha_list[lpha_list.index(word)])
                    word = word[0:-1]
                    n = alpha_list.append(word)
                    list_of_noalpha.append(char)
        (return what????)
```

When called like this:

```
hello_worddict("Male, rool, rool, hello 'bro !!!!! \jKr22vy")
```

Should return:

```
output = {"'": 1, 'vy': 1, '!': 5, '2': 2, 'bro': 1, 'rool': 2, 'Male': 1, 'hello': 1, 'Kr': 1, ',': 3}
```

Comment: You're not using `worddict` variable, `new_list` variable and `remover` function. Are you sure the `return` is the only problem?

Comment: I’m not understanding the goal of the function. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your rules for the output aren't clear. In particular where did the `\ ` go and why is `Kr` not `jKr`? In case you're confused, `\j` is two characters not an escape.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember Python comes with lots of batteries included. Apart from the questions over the backslash in your string, here's the easy way to do the splitting:

```
import re
import collections

def hello_worddict(doc):
    return collections.Counter(
        w for w in re.split(r'(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+|.)', s) if w.strip())
```